# According to Jehovah's witnesses, why does an active force have a name?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, pneumatology, names-of-god

> Matthew 28:19 Go ye therefore, and teach all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost: (KJV)

From my understanding of Jehovah's witness theology, the father's name is Jehovah, and the son's name is Jesus Christ, and the Holy Ghost is God's active force. What is the name of the Holy Ghost? If there is none, what is the explanation for this verse? And why would an active force have a name?

Comment: Typically "in the name of" means "by the authority of", so I'm not sure of the relevance of actual names to this verse.

Comment: I figured something like that would come up. I want to see what the explanation is according to their view. Some explanations would add questions. That would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Does my answer suits your needs ? If so, please mark it as preferred answer. If not, please comment on it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made some research on their site : wol.jw.org. Based on this verse, here is an article from their 03/15/2010 Watchtower, titled ["Baptized in the Name of Whom and What?"](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010204#h=1).

The part under ["In the Name of the Holy Spirit"](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010204#h=20) should interest you. Here is the most relevant part :

> What does it mean to be baptized in the name of the holy spirit? As
>   noted earlier, those hearing Peter on the day of Pentecost were aware
>   of the holy spirit. In fact, they could see proof right before their
>   eyes that God continued to use the holy spirit. Peter was one of those
>   who had been “filled with holy spirit and [who had] started to speak
>   with different tongues.” (Acts 2:4, 8) **The expression “in the name of”
>   need not imply the name of a person. Today, many things are done “in
>   the name of the government,” which is not a person. They are done by
>   the authority of the government. Similarly, one who is baptized in the
>   name of the holy spirit recognizes that the holy spirit is, not a
>   person, but Jehovah’s active force.** And such baptism means that one
>   acknowledges the role the holy spirit plays in God’s purpose.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Sorry for the late acceptance, I can only really get on once a week or so.